# Не собирается проект Veyon 4.0.4

Tags: c++, c

При сборке проекта выдает следующую ошибку:

> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/unixpw.c:56:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:12:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:1:22: error: redefinition of
>   'default8x16FontData'  static unsigned char
>   default8x16FontData[4096+1]={
>                         ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/userinput.c:7758:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:11:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:1:22: note: previous definition of 'default8x16FontData' was here
>    static unsigned char default8x16FontData[4096+1]={
>                         ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/unixpw.c:56:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:12:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:259:12: error: redefinition of 'default8x16FontMetaData'
>    static int default8x16FontMetaData[256*5+1]={
>               ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/userinput.c:7758:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:11:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:259:12: note: previous definition of 'default8x16FontMetaData' was here
>    static int default8x16FontMetaData[256*5+1]={
>               ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/unixpw.c:56:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:12:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:261:20: error: redefinition of 'default8x16Font'
>    static rfbFontData default8x16Font = { default8x16FontData, default8x16FontMetaData };
>                       ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/userinput.c:7758:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:11:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:261:20: note: previous definition of 'default8x16Font' was here
>    static rfbFontData default8x16Font = { default8x16FontData, default8x16FontMetaData };
>                       ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/scan.c:2457:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:27:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:1:22: error: redefinition of 'default8x16FontData'
>    static unsigned char default8x16FontData[4096+1]={
>                         ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/unixpw.c:56:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:12:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:1:22: note: previous definition of 'default8x16FontData' was here
>    static unsigned char default8x16FontData[4096+1]={
>                         ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/scan.c:2457:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:27:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:259:12: error: redefinition of 'default8x16FontMetaData'
>    static int default8x16FontMetaData[256*5+1]={
>               ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/unixpw.c:56:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:12:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:259:12: note: previous definition of 'default8x16FontMetaData' was here
>    static int default8x16FontMetaData[256*5+1]={
>               ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/scan.c:2457:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:27:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:261:20: error: redefinition of 'default8x16Font'
>    static rfbFontData default8x16Font = { default8x16FontData, default8x16FontMetaData };
>                       ^
>
> In file included from ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/unixpw.c:56:0,
>                    from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:12:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/default8x16.h:261:20: note: previous definition of 'default8x16Font' was here
>    static rfbFontData default8x16Font = { default8x16FontData, default8x16FontMetaData };
>                       ^
>
> In file included from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:37:0:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/sslhelper.c: In function 'check_vnc_tls_mode':
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/sslhelper.c:1937:3: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
>      ((uint32_t *)buf)[0] = Swap32IfLE(len);
>      ^
>
> In file included from ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:56:0:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/x11vnc.c: At top level:
>   ../3rdparty/x11vnc/src/x11vnc.c:1919:0: warning: "SHOW_NO_PASSWORD_WARNING" redefined
>    #define SHOW_NO_PASSWORD_WARNING \
>    ^
>
> ../plugins/vncserver/x11vnc-builtin/x11vnc-veyon.c:53:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
>    #define SHOW_NO_PASSWORD_WARNING 0
>    ^

Ссылка на [default8x16.h](https://github.com/veyon/x11vnc/blob/032bce418f2cc451e787719aaa9a987a8f8fe5c6/src/default8x16.h)

Ссылка на [unixpw.c](https://github.com/veyon/x11vnc/blob/032bce418f2cc451e787719aaa9a987a8f8fe5c6/src/unixpw.c)

Ссылка на [userinput.c](https://github.com/veyon/x11vnc/blob/master/src/userinput.c)

Ссылка на [scan.c](https://github.com/veyon/x11vnc/blob/master/src/scan.c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тут ясно всё написано:

Определение

```
#define SHOW_NO_PASSWORD_WARNING 0
```

в строке 53 файла x11vnc-veyon.c дублирует определение

```
#define SHOW_NO_PASSWORD_WARNING 0
```

в строке 1919 файла x11vnc.c.

Почему так получилось - ответ довольно очевидный: неправильно написан makefile. Ну, или файл проекта составлен неправильно, если Вы работаете в некоторой IDE. Что это за проект ? Кто его составлял?

Такое впечатление, что либо два **разных** проекта склеились в один, либо где-то у Вас напутано в #ifdef.